# How do I make a "composite key" (and what is this even called)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, computer-science, theory

I have two key strings, representing two objects of two different classes of objects. The keys are unique within their classes. I need to create a unique key representing the combination of these two keys. How do I do this?

I can't just concatenate them, because any character could be present in the base keys. I could maybe escape the concatenation delimiter before I concatenate? I could create a hash of the two keys, but this feels heavy.

Are there built in functions to help me do this? Is this "called something"? It seems like this would be a common (solved) problem.

(I'm looking for this specifically in Javascript, but I'm curious about higher level solutions or frameworks as well)

Comment: Can't you just create a "key" object that has both object's keys in it? This would be unique and you could access the keys afterwards

Comment: i'm looking to use a unique string (composite key?) as a reference to the two objects. it needs to be a unique string.  ps — why the downvotes? this seems like a valid question. if anyone wants to help me phrase it better or clarify, be my guest.

Comment: If the composite key needs to be a string, I'd say just go with the delimiter option, e.g. URL-encode both strings, then concatenate them with an `&` character.

Comment: that's what i am thinking too. i'm very surprised there isn't a built in function to do this... it seems like it would be a common need. i still wonder if there is actually a name for it that i'm not aware of.

Comment: BTW the term "composite key" or "compound key" does exist; it doesn't refer to a concatenation of keys, just the fact that an object is identified by a set of properties instead of a single one.

Comment: Well, it's not that common outside RDBM's, and those have their own internal ways of dealing with this. In programmatic models we tend to just use serial numbers or basic string ID's, at least in my experience.

Comment: yes, i'm familiar with the concept in terms of relational databases, but i am wondering if there is an analogue for scripting languages, and if there are functions to help me generate the key string automatically

Comment: What is the use case for this? It would help us a lot if you could give us an example of where this would be needed

Comment: Note that by URL encoding and delimiting with & (which seems like a perfectly fine idea), you're adding a little burden to the context to *know* what kind of key is being held.  i.e. am I holding an individual key, that allows arbitrary &s, or is this an encoded conjunctive key, which must have exactly one &.  A key object, like others have suggested, could be used to represent either the and individual or a conjunction, and it would know which kind it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply concatenate the two strings, but prefix the first string with its length, and a separator. For example, if the input strings are `"cat"` and `"doorbell"`, the output string would be `"3:catdoorbell"`. On the other hand, if the inputs were `"catdoor"` and `"bell"`, the output would be `"7:catdoorbell"`.

With this method, the outputs are unique, and the original keys are recoverable from the output string.

Answer (score 1):

Create a third type of object that has it's own key (or not, the key is optional) to track all the combinations. If you are dynamically creating these entries you may want something to check and enforce the uniqueness of the values.

I usually call this a crosswalk table or a linking table.

The wiki page covering this topic calls it an Associative Entity
[Wikipedia - Associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)